# How to reset Siri authorization status to undetermined?

Tags: permissions, ios10, siri, sirikit

After an app has asked permission to use Siri, how do you reset the authorization status so that the app will ask permission to use Siri again? That is, how do I hit INSiriAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined again after it has already been hit?

I know you can reset Location & Privacy permissions by navigating to Settings->General->Reset->Reset Location & Privacy but it doesn't reset the Siri permissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out you just have to remove and reinstall the app. Haven't figured out a way to do it in Settings.

Answer (score -2):

You can do it under Settings > Siri > App Support

Comment: This is an incomplete answer. Going to Settings -> Siri -> App Support does not answer my question.